# How to do calculation just before a Gesture's touchesbegan triggers in a way so that it wont block or delay the gesture?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm sorry but I have read every single page about it and still can't fix this problem. In short, I have a UIView (Yellow) in my viewcontroller(Black) and I'm adding a UIlongGestureRecognizer on it within the UIView (So that I can enable it when the user touches in blue areas and disable it when they don't) and I'm adding a UIPanGestureRecognizer on the UIView from ViewController's Class so I can enable it when the user is touching the Yellow area so it can pan the whole Yellow UIView. I need to know which blue rect has been touched so I can Remove it and in order to do that, every blue rect has an index. But The problem is that on the first touch, firstly I want to know the touched index (I get the touched Index in my InsideView's touchesBegan method) before UILongPressGesture's TouchesBegan Method gets called so I use `[super touchesBegan"touches withEvent:event];` inside LongPress's touchesBegan but on "first" touch it blocks the gesture from doing anything else after it gets the index, but on the next touch it works and removes the rect. This problem also gets repeated after each time the pan gets enabled, so LongPressGesture doesn't work right on the first touch after pan. (In my ZCSHoldProgress class, I'm using `self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan;` in another method (not in touchesBegan which is as usual)) I'd truly appreciate any help.[image]

```
       ////  InsideView.h (My UIView which is inside my ViewController)

        @protocol InsideViewDelegate <NSObject>
        -(void)enablePan;
        -(void)disablePan;
        @end

        @interface InsideView : UIView  <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
        @property (nonatomic,weak)id<InsideViewDelegate>delegate;
        @end

        ////  InsideView.m   (My UIView which is inside my ViewController)

        #import "InsideView.h"
        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
        #import "ZCSHoldProgress.h"

        @interface InsideView(){
            BOOL panIsEnabled;
            BOOL TapAndHoldIsEnabled;
        }
        @property (nonatomic) int rectIndex;

        @property (strong, nonatomic) ZCSHoldProgress * tapAndHoldToRemovePoint;
        @property (strong, nonatomic) NSValue * discoveryCGPointValue;
        @property (nonatomic) CGPoint discoveryCGPoint;
        @end

        @implementation InsideView

        - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
            self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
            if (self) {

                _rectIndex=-1;

                //Boolians
                panIsEnabled=NO;
                TapAndHoldIsEnabled=NO;
                [self.delegate disableDoneButton];

            }
            return self;
        }


        -(void) setupTapAndHoldGesture{
            self.tapAndHoldToRemovePoint = [[ZCSHoldProgress alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(HandleTapAndHold:)];
            self.tapAndHoldToRemovePoint.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;
            self.tapAndHoldToRemovePoint.allowableMovement =0.0;
            self.tapAndHoldToRemovePoint.delaysTouchesBegan=NO;
        //    self.tapAndHoldToRemovePoint.delaysTouchesEnded=NO;
            [self.tapAndHoldToRemovePoint setEnabled:YES];
        }
        -(void)enableTapAndHoldToRemove{
            TapAndHoldIsEnabled=YES;
            [self addGestureRecognizer:self.tapAndHoldToRemovePoint];
            for (UIGestureRecognizer * g in self.gestureRecognizers) {
                if ([g isMemberOfClass:[self.tapAndHoldToRemovePoint class]])
                    g.enabled=YES;
            }
        }
        -(void)disableTapAndHoldToRemove{
            TapAndHoldIsEnabled=NO;
            [self removeGestureRecognizer:self.tapAndHoldToRemovePoint];
            for (UIGestureRecognizer * g in self.gestureRecognizers) {
                if ([g isMemberOfClass:[self.tapAndHoldToRemovePoint class]])
                    g.enabled=NO;
            }
        }

        - (void) HandleTapAndHold:(ZCSHoldProgress *)gestureRecognizer {

            if(_rectIndex!=-1 && TapAndHoldIsEnabled){
                NSLog(@"--> isTapAndHoldEnabled =YES");

                if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
                    NSLog(@"HandleTapToRemove -->  Began");
                } else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
                    NSLog(@" --> Changed");
                    [self.tapAndHoldToRemovePoint tearDown];
                } else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) {
                    NSLog(@" --> Cancelled");
                    [self.tapAndHoldToRemovePoint tearDown];
                }else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
                    NSLog(@" --> Ended so removeRect”);
                    [self removePoint];
                    [self.tapAndHoldToRemovePoint tearDown];

                    panIsEnabled=YES;
                    [self.delegate enablePan];
                }else {
                    return;
                }
            }else{
                NSLog(@"--> isTapAndHoldEnabled=NO”);
                return;
            }
        }

        -(void)removeRect{
            int rectToBeRemove =[self _rectIndex];
            [self.finalPointsArray removeObjectAtIndex:rectToBeRemove];
            [self setNeedsDisplay];
        }

        - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
             CGPoint touchedPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

                    CGRect discoveryRect = CGRectZero;
                    for (int j=0; j<self.finalRectsArray.count;j++){
                        self.discoveryCGPointValue = [finalRectsArray objectAtIndex:j];
                        self.discoveryCGPoint =self.discoveryCGPointValue.CGPointValue;
                        discoveryRect = CGRectMake(self.discoveryCGPoint.x-15, self.discoveryCGPoint.y-15, 30, 30);

                        if(CGRectContainsPoint(discoveryRect,touchedPoint) ) {
                            ////// Rect is touched —> Activate Long Gesture & Disable Pan //////////
                            _rectIndex=j;
                            break;
                        }else{
                            ////// Didn’t touch Rect —> Disable Long Gesture & Enable Pan ////////
                            _rectIndex=-1;
                        }
                    }

                    if (_rectIndex!=-1){
                         //////Enabling LongPress Gesture & Disabling Pan //////////

                        [self setupTapAndHoldGesture];
                        [self enableTapAndHoldToRemove];

                        [self.delegate disablePan];
                        panIsEnabled =NO;

                    }else{
                        [self disableTapAndHoldToRemove];

                        [self.delegate enablePan];
                        panIsEnabled=YES;
                    }
           }
        }

        - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
            CGPoint touchedPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
                    [self disableTapAndHoldToRemove];
        }

        - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

                if (!panIsEnabled){
                    panIsEnabled=YES;
                    [self.delegate enablePan];
                }
                // If I enable the TapAndHoldIsEnabled here, on first touch on the blue rect, LongPressGesture’s touches began gets called without knowing what blue rect has been touched even though it only gets activated when a blue rect is touched.

                //        if (!isTapAndHoldEnabled){
                //            [self setupTapAndHoldGesture];
                //            [self enableTapAndHoldToRemove];
                //        }
                [self setNeedsDisplay];
                return;
            }
        }

        @end
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///ImmediatePanGestureRecognizer.m  (This is my pan Gesture Subclass)

#import "ImmediatePanGestureRecognizer.h"
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@implementation ImmediatePanGestureRecognizer
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        if (self.state >= UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            return;
        }
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan;
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //  ZCSHoldProgress.m   (This is my Long Press Gesture Subclass)

        #import "ZCSHoldProgress.h"
        #import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

        @interface ZCSHoldProgress ()

        - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
              _canRemovePoint=NO;
              UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[touches anyObject];
              UIView *view = nil;
              for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in touch.gestureRecognizers) {
                    if ([recognizer isEqual:self]) 
                       view = recognizer.view;
                       break;
                    }
              }
              self.startingPoint = [touch locationInView:view];
              self.lastTouches = touches;
              [self setup];
         }
        - (void)setup {
            if (self.progressTimer == nil) {
                self.progressTimer =
                    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
                self.startDate = [NSDate new];
            }
        }

        - (void)handleTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
            NSTimeInterval timerElapsed = [[NSDate new] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startDate];
            self.should_trigger = timerElapsed >= self.minimumPressDuration;
            if (timerElapsed >= self.displayDelay && self.progressView == nil) {
                [self setupProgressView];
            }
            if (self.should_trigger && !self.is_triggered) {
                self.is_triggered = YES;

                self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan;

                [self.myTarget performSelector:self.myAction withObject:self afterDelay:0.0];
            }
            [self updateProgressLayer:(timerElapsed / self.minimumPressDuration)];
        }
        @end

     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////MyViewController.m    (This is my View Controller Class)
    #import "ImmediatePanGestureRecognizer.h"
    #import "ZCSHoldProgress.h"
    @interface SelectionVC (){
         BOOL panIsAllowed;
    }
    @property (nonatomic,strong) InsideView * insideV;

    @property (strong, nonatomic) ImmediatePanGestureRecognizer * pan;

    @end

    @implementation MyViewController
      -(void)setupPan{
        self.pan= [[ImmediatePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanInSelectionVC:)];
        self.pan.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
        self.pan.delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
        self.pan.delegate = self;
    }
    -(void)enablePan{
        [self setupPan];
        [myMainView addGestureRecognizer:self.pan];
        for (UIGestureRecognizer * g in myMainView.gestureRecognizers) {
            if ([g isMemberOfClass:[ImmediatePanGestureRecognizer class]])
                g.enabled=YES;
        }
    }
    -(void)disablePan{
        self.pan.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        [myMainView removeGestureRecognizer:self.pan];
        for (UIGestureRecognizer * g in myMainView.gestureRecognizers) {
             if ([g isMemberOfClass:[ImmediatePanGestureRecognizer class]]){
                 g.enabled=NO;
             }
         }
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Could you upload demo repo and add a link to the question? I think i will be easier to help you

Comment: It's a very big class, and it would only make it more confusing if I do, what it does is to basically control two gestures from another class (Pan form its superView which is my controller) and one gesture(Long Press) from within the UIVIew class and the only thing I want it to do is when user longPress on a rect, it should trigger the longpress gesture (and knowing which rect it touched) and anywhere except that, it should trigger the pan gesture.

Comment: I made the code more readable, I truly would appreciate any help. Thank you all.

Comment: Ok i got it. You want move yellow view when dragging. When user have a long touch, you want to know which blue rect is touched. Is it right?

Comment: Blue rects are actually cgpoints which I want to remove and thats after the long press's state has ended, so when user does a longpress on a blue rect, that cgpoint will be removed, other wise if user touches anywhere on the uiview except for those blue rects, the pan gesture will become active so user will be able to pan the UIView (insideView). I showed those blue rects to simplify the problem but in fact they are rects which contain one cgpoint so i can understand which cgpoint is going to be removed after a longpress (and i could get that by examining all blue rects in that four loop)

Comment: In my insideView'a touchesBegan method, longpress gesture gets activated when user longpresses a blue rect but then it won't do anything else, it wont go to its end state to remove the point. Thats what im stuck in

Comment: Actually i'm still confused about your question. But as i understand, you should use `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` instead of `touchesBegan` to enable or disable gestures.

Comment: Im only using the touchesBegan method inside my UIView to understand where the user is touching so i can then enable/disable the longpress gesture and pan gesture, otherwise i couldn't understand where the user is touching (in the blue rect area or out of it, which is the yellow area)

Comment: You can get where user is touching with `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`. Can we discuss on chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161134/discussion-between-trungduc-and-reza-ab).

Comment: Yes of course, I truly do appreciate it.

Comment: Let click on `continue this discussion in chat.` on my above comment.